# AWS S3 Bucket Policy Network Failure - verify permissions to access-analyzer:ValidatePolicy in IAM to use policy validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In AWS Solution Architect I am performing Module 3 Challenge Lab Creating a Static Website for the Cafe using AWS S3.

I want to Grant read-only permission to anonymous user
I followed [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) and pasted the required JSON code in my bucket policy

my Bucket Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::website-22-4-28-main/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error message for the above bucket policy

[image: Error Description]

I would like to know how can I resolve this error.
TIA

Comment: This message is not related to the policy you posted. You are getting an error for the access analyzer widget on that page. The IAM user does not have permissions to use the access analyzer and so you see the error (you would see similar errors on many other pages if you don't have permissions). My students were seeing this error message in the Architecting on AWS course last week.

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks a lot! :)
True indeed, I had checked IAM and I didn't have a permission to use `access-analyzer`. Due to this problem I kept `Bucket-Policy` empty, and used `ACL` for making `objects` public instead, that's why I got 82/100 score for this lab, fortunately that was enough to pass the lab. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is because the IAM user doesn't have permission to use the access analyzer. If you are doing the AWS Cloud Archeticting course challenge lab I think you can ignore this error and just continue with creating your policy as usual. just make sure to copy and paste the exact code from the documentation and replace the resource name with your amazon resource name (arn).